# how to display a custom list data on the app page in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: firebase subcollections image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rcF6.png)[https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI2Cp.png">][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rcF6.png)

i have tried this code to retrieve data from subcollection of the same name(userProducts) stored in many firebase documents.How do i display this data in a container on the app page ? I tried using listiew.builder but it doesnt work.
The first function

```
 static List<products> finalProductsList = [] ;
  productsList() async
  {
    List list_of_products = await Firestore.instance.collection("products")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((val) => val.documents);
    for (int i=0; i<list_of_products.length; i++)
    {
      Firestore.instance.collection("products").document(
          list_of_products[i].documentID.toString()).collection("userProducts").snapshots().listen(CreateListofProducts);
    }
  }
```

Second function

```
 CreateListofProducts(QuerySnapshot snapshot)async
  {
    var docs = snapshot.documents;
    for (var Doc in docs)
    {
      finalProductsList.add(products.fromFireStore(Doc));
    }
    }
```

CourseModel

```
class products {
  final String prodId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String username;
  final String price;
  final String productname;
  final String details;
  final String color;
  final String composition;
  final String washandcare;
  final String sizeandfit;
  final String shopmediaUrl;
  final String id;
  final dynamic likes;
  products({ this.prodId,
    this.ownerId,
    this.username,
    this.price,
    this.details,
    this.productname,
    this.color,
    this.composition,
    this.washandcare,
    this.sizeandfit,
    this.shopmediaUrl,
    this.id,
    this.likes,});

  factory products.fromFireStore(DocumentSnapshot doc)
  {
    Map data = doc.data ;
    return products(
      prodId: doc['prodId'],
      ownerId: doc['ownerId'],
      username: doc['username'],
      price: doc['price'],
      productname: doc['productname'],
      details: doc['details'],
      shopmediaUrl: doc['shopmediaUrl'],
      color:doc['color'],
      composition:doc['composition'],
      washandcare:doc['washandcare'],
      sizeandfit:doc['sizeandfit'],
      likes: doc['likes'],
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

SO if i understand you, you want to get data on multiple collections on multiple documents?

If so... you should use `collecionGroup`, you can learn how to use [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html), make sure to adjust your firestore rules.

Comment: no,ive edited the image and the codes.See if you can understand now.